# Question about eigenvalues of connectivity matrices for graphs

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues, spectral-graph-theory

I'm a computer science student working on a research project that deals with computational study of atomic clusters. I'm using a graph based representation of the clusters using a binary connectivity matrix. My question is, are the eigenvalues invariant to a transformation in particle indices?

For example, if I have a 3 particle cluster with particle 1 attached to 2 and 2 attached to 3. The connectivity matrix will be different if I swapped the particle index even though it is the same structure. My question is will the eigenvalues be the same? I checked it using python and indeed, the values were same, but I'm trying to look for a formal established proof (or an article to cite).

I really appreciate the help and I apologize if it is a stupid question.

Comment: Hi! First, welcome to MathOverflow: this website is intended for mathematicians to ask research questions to each other. MathStackExchange (or MathSE) is for other questions about mathematics. Second, the eigenvalues should not depend on how you choose to name your vertices. Lastly, your question is not stupid, this is just not the right place to ask it. (I dare say that many of us once asked how to compute the volume of a sphere and where the formula comes from; it's far from being a stupid question, but it's not a research question of current mathematics.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $P$ is a *[permutation matrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix)*, i.e., $P$ is binary and doubly stochastic, then $P^\top = P^{-1}$. Thus, any matrix $A$ is co-spectral to $P^\top A P$. Furthermore, if the matrix $A$ is the incidence matrix of a graph, then a straightforward exercise shows that the latter is a relabeling of the indices of the graph.

Answer (score 0):

If you permute the indices i.e., rename each of the particles, the eigenvalues will stay the same. The eigenvectors will be what they were before but with the indices permuted.

i.e., if [2,8,6] was an eigenvector before, with 2 corresponding to the first particle, 8 the 2nd particle, and 6 the 3rd, and you switch the 2nd and third indices so that what was before the 2nd particle is now the 3rd and what was the 3rd particle is now the 2nd, then [2,6,8] will be the new eigenvector.